# Can someone help me port a gameboy emulator to ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, emulation, porting

How can I translate a Qt (c++) gameboy emulator to a qml ubuntu touch emulator? Any suggestions would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That question might be out of the scope of this site.

Which Game Boy emulator would you like to translate?

It may be worth asking on the following websites

- http://ucollective.org/
- http://www.chipmusic.org/

Comment: I wanna start simple with gameboy-emu on github it's just an emulator for the original... but it's in qt... so i figure it'd be the easiest...